# My list is not behaving as I intend it to. Keeps inserting the same values

Tags: python

So I'm coding my first Python program from scratch, a snake game, after spending a day learning what I knew from C and translating it to python.

I have a class with two lists, a position and a body. Supposedly, what my program is doing when it hits the fruit is inserting the updated position value at the forefront of the list. However, when it hits the fruit, it just adds another value that is always the same as the previous one.

```
class Snake(object):
 def __init__(self):
     self.pos = [width//2, height//2]
     self.mov = "UP"
     self.body = [[width//2, height//2]]

 def move(self, eat):
     if self.mov == "UP": self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] - SPEED
     if self.mov == "DOWN": self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] + SPEED
     if self.mov == "LEFT": self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] - SPEED
     if self.mov == "RIGHT": self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] + SPEED
     self.body.insert(0, self.pos)

     if not eat:
        self.body.pop()
```

Inside my loop,

```
eat = vars.check_food(snake, food)
snake.move(eat)
```

The eat check works as intended.

Imagine eat is False for the most part, the first snakeling has a body of [[100,100]]. When it hits the fruit and eat becomes True for a frame, it starts being [[100,100],[100,100]] instead of like [[101,101],[100,100]].

I'm almost sure it's an error on my thought process but for the life of me I can't find it. Have an old position -> add a new one -> remove old one if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `insert` you're inserting `self.pos`, not a copy of it. So when you change `self.pos` on the next iteration, all the instances change at the same time.

You need to be explicit on making a copy of an object in Python:

```
self.body.insert(0, self.pos[:])
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed this! What kind of variable behaves like this, lists only or everything?

Comment: @user2241851 absolutely everything. Many objects like numbers and strings are immutable so you'll never see this kind of problem with them, but you'll often see it with `dict` for example.